# how to run the yarn commands from a spark application

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

Hi I am trying to run yarn commands like

yarn logs

yarn application -list

yarn application -kill

am trying to use yarnclient but facing issues.

```
 package com.ankush
 import java.io.Serializable

 import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ApplicationId
 import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.YarnClient
 import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf._
 import org.apache.spark._
 import org.apache.spark.streaming._

 object SparkFiller extends Serializable{
  private var appId: ApplicationId = null
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={

     try {

  var counter =0

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkFiller")//.setMaster("local[*]")
  val conf: YarnConfiguration = new YarnConfiguration()

  // println("test")
  sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
  val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
  lines.foreachRDD(
    rdd => {
      if(rdd.isEmpty())
      {
        counter+=1
        if(counter>4)
        {
          println("Testing")
          val conf: YarnConfiguration = new YarnConfiguration()
          val client = YarnClient.createYarnClient()
          client.init(conf)
          client.start()
          val newApp = client.createApplication()
          client.getApplications()

          val test = client.getApplications()
          println(test)

          counter=0
          //        val result = "sh /home/ankush/test.sh".!
          //              ssc.stop()
        }
      }

      rdd.foreachPartition(part => {
        // val dbsender = new PushToDocumentDB();
        part.foreach(msg =>{
          println(msg)
        })

      })
    })



  ssc.start()

  ssc.awaitTermination()


}
catch {

  case runtime: RuntimeException=> {
    1
  }
}


   }

 }
```

Then am facing errors like

```
  Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-13" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.TimelineClient.createTimelineClient(TimelineClient.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createTimelineClient(YarnClientImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceInit(YarnClientImpl.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
```

Using this application am trying to do if there is no data flowing through the socket for certain amount of time I want to list the applications on the yarn and kill another application which will be sending data to the socket.

Thanks,

Ankush Reddy.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey jar is missing in classpath, add [jersey-bundle jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.19) to spark-submit.

```
spark-submit --jars jersey-bundle-x.y.z.jar \
...........
```

or

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=\\<path>jersey-bundle-x.y.z.jar" \
.......
```

Comment: I have included it in the pom.xml and able to see it in the jar am building it along with the application jar.

Comment: Add `hadoop classpath` command output to spark.executor.extraClassPath then try.